# RecyclerView not loading properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a chat app which should load chats with recyclerview and an edittext below the recyclerview and an imagebutton to the right of the edittext.

I have a relativelayout within which I have a recyclerview and another relative layout. Within this 2nd relativelayout, I have an edittext and an imagebutton. However the recyclerview is not loading properly.

[image]

I want the recyclerview to load till the start of the edittext without any white space in between.

layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_im"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.abdralabs.talksee.IMActivity"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_im"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="8.5"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_im"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.5">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_im"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter message..."
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_im"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

activity.java file

```
public class IMActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ImAdapter imAdapter;
    private List<ChatMsg> chatMsgList = new ArrayList<>();
    EditText etIp;
    Button setIp;
    Button setOn;
    EditText messageInput;
    Button sendButton;
    ServiceConnection serviceConnection;
    TalkSeeService.TalkSeeBinder talkSeeBinder;
    String otherUserName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        bindService(new Intent(IMActivity.this, TalkSeeService.class), new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                talkSeeBinder = (TalkSeeService.TalkSeeBinder)service;
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                talkSeeBinder = null;
            }
        },BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_im);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        otherUserName = intent.getStringExtra("otherUserName");
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_im);
        imAdapter = new ImAdapter(chatMsgList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(imAdapter);

        prepareChatData();
    }


    private void prepareChatData() {
        ChatMsg chatMsg = new ChatMsg(otherUserName);
        chatMsgList.add(chatMsg);

        imAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_swipe, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                break;
            case R.id.log_out:
                Intent i2 = new Intent(this,LauncherActivity.class);
                i2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                LoggedInSharedPreference.clearUserName(getApplicationContext());
                startActivity(i2);
                break;
            case R.id.recent_conversations:
                Intent rcIntent = new Intent(this,HistoryActivity.class);
                startActivity(rcIntent);
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(this,"Somthing went wrong. Please try again!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Adapter code missing.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_im"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.abdralabs.talksee.IMActivity"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_im"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="8.5"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_im"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.5">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_im"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter message..."
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_im"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are changing the data of **chatMsgList** , which is the local variable.
When you call **notifyDataSetChanged()** , it wont work .

To make it work , create a new function with any name and call it in **prepareChatData()** like this

```
private void prepareChatData() {
    ChatMsg chatMsg = new ChatMsg(otherUserName);
    chatMsgList.add(chatMsg);
    imAdapter.swapData(chatMsgList);
}
```

Inside your Adapter implement this method

```
public void swapData(Cursor chatMsgList) {
  myChatlistArray = chatMsgList;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LinearLayout` when using `layout_weight` attribute :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_im"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.abdralabs.talksee.IMActivity"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_im"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="8.5"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_im"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1.5">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_im"
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter message..."
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_im"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.abdralabs.talksee.IMActivity"
    android:id="@+id/activity_im"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_im"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/rl_im"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_im"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_im"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter message..."
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ib_im"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ib_im"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```